# Is "awesomely beautiful" used in this sentence verbosity?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

> "What an awe! I was awestruck by her **awesomely beautiful** face."

Is **awesomely beautiful** verbosity?

Comment: That's used in informal conversation to mean outstandingly, extraordinarily, very.

Comment: One person's verbosity is another person's reinforcement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is **awesomely beautiful** verbosity?

YES. It is essentially verbose as the writing style is verbose.

If we are to look at it from a literary point of view, there's a style called [**repetition**](http://literarydevices.net/repetition/).

> **Repetition** is a literary device that repeats the same words or phrases a few times to make an idea clearer. There are several types of repetitions commonly used in both prose and poetry.
>
> As a rhetorical device, it could be a word, a phrase or a full sentence or a poetical line repeated to emphasize its significance in the entire text. Repetition is not distinguished solely as a figure of speech but more as a rhetorical device.

Specifically:

[**Polyptoton**](http://literarydevices.net/polyptoton/)

> Repetition of words of the same root with different endings.
>
> Polyptoton is a use of **excessive words** instead of shorter expressions. It involves an indirect way of expressing things. These words can help embellish sentences to create striking effects. In fact, it happens when the grammatical meaning can be expressed by using syntactical construction instead of morphological marking.
>
> ‘With eager **feeding food** doth choke the **feeder**….”
>   (Richard II by William Shakespeare)